# Get friends like in facebook?

Tags: facebook

I am looking out for a way to find the "Likes" of my friends. Hence the rest url using graph api would be something like,

> https://graph.facebook.com/user_id_some_number/likes?access_token=access_token

Please note that user_id_some_number is the ID something like 12302892734748 and access_token is the access token.

However, this returns me an empty data as follows,

```
{
   "data": [      
   ]
}
```

I am not sure why it does not work? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for your time.

Cheers,
Abhishek

Comment: Did any answer help you? Just click the check mark to mark it as an accepted solution or vote it up. And please check your other questions for possible solutions, too. Thanks! :)   (And yes, this is copy-pasted so new users are aware of the voting system.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double-check if you've got the users **friends_likes** data permission.

> **friends_likes** Provides access to the
>   list of all of the pages the user has
>   liked as the likes connectionliked as the likes connection

Reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

Edit:

Your Syntax worked for me

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "BookBooN.com",
         "category": "Application",
         "id": "48503876751",
         "created_time": "2010-09-01T09:33:42+0000"
      },
      {
         "name": "New Zealand",
         "category": "Travel",
         "id": "154058198218",
         "created_time": "2010-08-29T21:30:30+0000"
      },
```

Your permission dialog should have this style

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have got permission for friends_likes as well. Its https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=access_token&scope=user_likes,friends_likes. Am I right?