# facebook api get friends likes returns empty array for some friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i tried this with fql and the test console

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

- checked the permissions
- check with two accounts (no privacy issues)
- checked the fb bugreports

clicking on friends then a user id then likes returns an empty array on some of my friends. i couldnt figure out why this is the case.

it seems to be pretty random but maybe i overlooked something

can someone help me on this?

Comment: Check [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741388/get-friends-like-in-facebook), you might be having the same issue.

Comment: No its not the same. i have the permissions. like i said: it just happens on some persons.

Comment: Facebook now returns only friends who are using your app. Please refer answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23417628

Answer (score 0):

If some person means Your app works fine for facebook developer account and other accounts not - check on You facebook developer account Status & review if Your app is On for public and not blocked for review.